# How to find dependency between objects files?

Tags: c, linux, object, archive

I have archive file that contains some objects files.

1) How can I find out if is there any dependency between objects files?

For example in [this article](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/ar-command-examples/) I have `multiplication.o subtraction.o` in `libarith.a`. So if I want use only in function from 1 object file I want to remove the rest of objects files (ignore from the compiler) from archive file.

So how can I check if multiplication.o depending with subtraction.o

2)How can I view all exported functions from archive/objects files?

Answer (score 1):

1) How can I find out if is there any dependency between objects files?

Object files don't specify specific dependencies on other specific object files.  Rather the object file linker notes what each object file exports, and what it requires to be resolved.  The resulting (executable) file that is output from the linker has no unresolved references.

Use the 'nm' utility. See man nm for detail.

Example:

```
$ nm somefile.o
```

It will list all text (code segment) symbols, and their offsets (with the letter "T").  It will list all undefined references (with the letter "U") that have to be resolved at link time.